# cx_Oracle handling of special characters

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-2.6, cx-oracle

I have a query that returns a CLOB which contains a large string. The string contains high ASCII characters, such as mu (ASCII 230) but when I call read on the CLOB, I get ? instead of mu.

If I run the same query in sqldeveloper, I get the text as expected. If I read it from a file, it reads correctly.

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
cursor.executed(myQuery)
pageDef = cursor.fetchone()

while pagedef != None:
    print(pageDef[1].read()) # The blob is in the second column
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in cx_Oracle?

I tried wrapping the read in codec.decode call but that did not make any difference.

Comment: `Connection.encoding` returns the character set name, what's yours?

Comment: It's US-ASCII. I did no set it myself so I assumed it will default to ASCII... Is US-ASCII only the first 128 characters by any chance?

Comment: Shouldn't you set the NLS_LANG env variable? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html

Comment: Theoretically, yes US-ASCII is only the first 128; though I think Oracle's implemented it as US7ASCII and I can't remember what's included. It could also be the client you're viewing the data in don't forget. It does sound as though your DB is in a super-set of ASCII (hopefully UTF-8 (implemented as AL32UTF8)), which means the encoding on your connection is incorrect.